# No OS found after installation from LiveUSB

Tags: boot, grub

I just tried to install ElementaryOS on my HP Probook. After the installer finishes, it reboots my computer, like normal. However, it does not boot upon restart. Instead, I get a black screen with white text that says "No OS Found" or something along those lines. GRUB does not appear to have loaded.

When I check the drive via the file browser using my LiveUSB stick, the OS files do appear to be installed on the hard drive, however it does not boot for some reason. I tried to install 3 times and got the same error. Please help!

EDIT: I fixed my issue by creating a 100MB "swap space" partition before my main filesystem.

Comment: Is it in UEFI mode

Comment: What do "Boot Options" (or something along those lines) say? You can access them by entering BIOS (UEFI) settings, usually be pressing F12, DEL, or anything else the laptop says when it's booting. I'm thinking that the OS is installed, but the boot loader isn't pointing to the hard drive, or whatever is there. How did you format your partitions? If the laptop is UEFI, you should create an EFI partition, so that information can be saved to it.

Comment: SuiciDoga - How would I check? I'm not sure.


@AleksandarStefanović In boot options I have "hard drive", "optical disk", "USB Drive", and "Network boot". Booting into hard drive gives me the same error. I believe that the installer used ext4 to format it.

Comment: I fixed my issue by creating a 100MB "swap space" partition before my main filesystem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed my issue by creating a 100MB "swap space" partition before my main filesystem.

Answer (score 0):

This could possibly mean that there isn't an EFI partition available, I think that that could be your problem. Try to reinstall, but this time create a 50MB "EFI partition" (something along those lines in the dropdown menu when you choose partition purpose) before any other partitions, and then create your partitions as usual. I remember I had a hard time booting, too, before adding this partition.

Comment: I don't see "EFI Partition" as an option in the dropdown menu, or anything EFI related.

Comment: Are you sure? Have you check under both "filesystem type" and "mount point"? I'm sorry that I'm not quite sure where the options are, because I'm doing this from memory...

Comment: I fixed my issue by creating a 100MB "swap space" partition before my main filesystem.